# How do I use a variable as a directory?

Tags: python-3.x, ftp

Hello and I'm wondering how to use the variable, `log_dir = ""` ,to some ftp code which is , `fh = open("log-dir\key_log.txt", 'rb')`, As you can see I don't know how to use the variable `log_dir` to find the text file and upload it, Bear in mind the text file is in the same directory as the code file!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this will work with you.

```
log_dir = os.fsencode("Path here")
fh = open(os.path.join(log_dir, "key_log.txt"), 'rb').decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please upvote and Accept the answer if it works with you. @MattJ